# How to create a list of objects by grouping them by a common name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have a list of ungrouped objects and i want to return a list of grouped objects by a common value

```
[{"name": "test", "group": "A"},{"name": "test2", "group": "B"},{"name": "test3", "group": "A"},{"name": "test4", "group": "B"}]
```

I want to return this

```
[{"group":"A","users":[{"name":"test"},{"name":"test3"}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Willem's answer is correct for the OP's question as asked, it is more common to want the grouping 'by' the common value and thus to want to obtain a mapping rather than a list thus:

```
from collections import defaultdict

users = [
    {"name": "test", "group": "A"},
    {"name": "test2", "group": "B"},
    {"name": "test3", "group": "A"},
    {"name": "test4", "group": "B"}]

users_by_group = defaultdict(list)

for user in users:
    users_by_group[user['group']].append(user)


#users_by_group:
#  A:
#  - group: A
#    name: test
#  - group: A
#    name: test3
#  B:
#  - group: B
#    name: test2
#  - group: B
#    name: test4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` of `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = [
    { 'group': g, 'users': [{'name': v['name']} for v in vs] }
    for k, vs in groupby(sorted(mylist, itemgetter('group')), itemgetter('group'))
]
```